# Allow custom attribute in wordpress patterns

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

Is it possible to allow custom attributes in Wordpress pattern?

```
 <h2 itemprop="title">Software Engineer</h2>
```

I want to adde the itemprop attribute to the headline. -> this dont work.

> This block contains unexpected or invalid content.

```
<!-- wp:heading {"level":2} -->
                <h2 class="headline" itemprop="title">Software Engineer</h2>
                <!-- /wp:heading -->
```

This will work, but it is prone to errors.

```
  <!-- wp:heading {"level":2} -->
                <h2 class="headline"><span itemprop="title">Software Engineer<span></h2>
                <!-- /wp:heading -->
```